# Tapestry5 and jQuery

Tags: jquery, tapestry

I've been trying to implement tapestry5-jquery 3.4.2 into a Tapestry 5.3.8 project and I seem to be stuck in a no win situation.

As advised I have changed

```
config.add(JQuerySymbolConstants.SUPPRESS_PROTOTYPE, "false");
config.add(JQuerySymbolConstants.JQUERY_ALIAS, "$j");
```

When doing this Tapestry doesn't seem to load jQuery components and simple code like this doesn't execute:

```
    $j("a").click(function(){
            alert("Let's see");
        });
```

However, when I try

```
config.add(JQuerySymbolConstants.SUPPRESS_PROTOTYPE, "true");
```

Tapestry now loads the components (my datepickers for example are now jQuery which is one intended use as it has greater browser support than the standard).

I would almost be ok with this except for the fact that a `t:any` on one of the pages uses the hibernate/stitch mixin, which after suppressing the prototype no longer works.

What am I doing wrong here or am I stuck in a dark corner of the Tapestry5/jQuery relationship?

Comment: Have you tried to define it with `contributeModuleManager` in `AppModule`, as a require.js module?

Comment: 1. Check if jquery is included into your pages. 2. Add var $j = jQuery; at the beginning of your page.